# jQuery click outside a div animates it closed works but must click twice to open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dev page set up here: http://dev.harryg.me/da/

On the side I have 3 divs that should animate open when clicked and animate closed when the title is clicked again.

I wanted to add the functionality so that when the user clicks somewhere else on the document all the divs will close. This almost works great, except that once a div has been opened and closed as a result of clicking outside the user must click twice on it to reopen it.

Any idea of the cause?

Here is my jQuery...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('h2.tab-title').toggle(function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'0px'}, {queue:false, duration: 500});
    }, function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'-338px'}, {queue:false, duration: 500});
    });

});
jQuery(".side-tab").click(function(){ return false; });
jQuery(document).bind("click", function() { jQuery(".side-tab").animate({left:'-338px'}, {queue:false, duration: 500}); });
```

Comment: You're using toggle. click one, it's on. click it again it's off, click it again it's on. close it some other way ...it's still **on**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yrJwv/1/)

Create an open and close event and trigger one or the other on subsequent clicks, trigger close on document click.

```
<div><h2 class="tab-title">h2</h2></div>
<div><h2 class="tab-title">h2</h2></div>
<div><h2 class="tab-title">h2</h2></div>
<div><h2 class="tab-title">h2</h2></div>
```

JS

```
$('h2.tab-title').on('open', function() {
    $(this).parent().animate({left:'0px'}, {queue:false, duration: 500}).data('open',true);
}).on('close', function() {
    $(this).parent().animate({left:'-338px'}, {queue:false, duration: 500}).data('open',false);
}).on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).parent().data('open')){
        $(this).trigger('close');
    }else{
        $(this).trigger('open');
    }
});
$(document).on('click', function(){
     $('h2.tab-title').trigger('close');
});

$('.side-tab').on('click', function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); }); // stop any click in the side tab from bubbling up to the document
```

Comment: can you suggest a less roundabout way of preventing the propagation of clicking inside than what I've used?

Comment: I did in my code. So much less roundabout you couldn't spot it.

Comment: but it doesn't seem to work. The div still closes when it's clicked. When I add my old method to your code it works

Comment: check this fork of your code. I changed a bit of css to differentiate between the `heading` and the `div`. The div closes no matter which element you click. http://jsfiddle.net/YuA9t/

Comment: Yes, because the div will have links, forms etc in it eventually. We wouldn't want it closing whilst a user is interacting with the content. If we add my old method in there it seems to solve it, but apparently this isn't an elegant way... Sorry I am not an expert a jQuery

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way will be to add a class, `opened` for example to div that was opened and then trigger `toggle` method for divs with this class. Called `toggle` method will handle the animation of closing. And of course `opened` class should be removed while toggling back to closed state, as **popnoodles** reminded me.

**EDIT:** Updated code that is behaving as you wanted:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('h2.tab-title').toggle(function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'0px'}, {queue:false, duration: 500});
        $(this).parent().addClass('opened');
    }, function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'-338px'}, {queue:false, duration: 500});
        $(this).parent().removeClass('opened');
    });

});
jQuery(".side-tab").click(function(){ return false; });
jQuery(document).bind("click", function() { jQuery(".opened h2.tab-title").trigger('click');});
```

Comment: @popnoodles True, I forgot to write that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change toggle to click, remove the second function and make a validation to check if its open or closed (like get the left attribute and check if less than 0 )

The first click call the first function and show the div.
When you click outside the div, the div closes.

When you click it again, you call the second function that is the close function! That's why is not working!